# Equating a function with a singularity to the Taylor expansion of a similar function with no singularity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

Assuming I have two functions defined as follows
$$f_H(t) = \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if}\; t = 0 \\
1 & \text{if}\; t > 0 \end{cases}$$
$$f_U(t)=1\ \text{for all}\ t$$
Clearly $f_H(t) = f_U(t)\ \text{for}\ t>0$. However, given that $f_H(t)$ has a singularity at $0$, am I able to say that $f_H(t)$ is equal to the taylor expansion of $f_U(t)\ \text{about}\ 0 \ \text{for}\ t>0$? if yes, does this stand for any situation such as the one below as well?
$$f_H(t) = \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if}\; t = 0 \\
e^t & \text{if}\; t > 0 \end{cases}$$
$$f_U(t)=e^t$$

Comment: The taylor expansion of $f_{U}(t)$ is just $1$ in the first case, so $f_{H}(t)$ is equal to $1$... except at $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the function is analytic on the interval in question, the function is equal to its Taylor series expansion. For example:

$$f_H(t) = \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if}\; t = 0 \\
e^t & \text{if}\; t > 0 \end{cases}$$

and

$$f_H(t) = \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if}\; t = 0 \\
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} & \text{if}\; t > 0 \end{cases}$$

are equivalent statements. So, if you can say that $ f_H(t) = f_U(t); t \in (0, \infty)$, you can say the same for the Taylor series of  $f_U(t)$. Be careful not to make any claims about the "Taylor series" of $f_H(t)$ itself though.